# Variables in SQLITE Python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, jupyter-notebook, pandasql

I am working in Jupyter Notebooks using *pandasql*, which uses *SQLight* syntax. I am trying to select entries from a certain month, depending on a variable. I am planning to create a Python function that will change the value of the variable being used, but right now I am trying to get "Parameterized Queries" to work.

My table has the columns `DATE PAYED, PAYEE, AMOUNT`

This is what my SQL query looks like:

```
varMonth= "01"
q = """
    SELECT
        *,
        strftime('%m', "DATE DUE") as "months"
    FROM 
        year2020
    WHERE 
        "months" = "01"    
"""
test2020 = sqldf(q, globals())
```

The above code successfully selects all entries from January. I want to change the *WHERE* conditional to compare against the variable `varMonth`.

I've seen there are different ways to pass a value in an SQL query, like `?, :1, :varMonth, %s, %(varMonth)s, +varMonth+`  but these don't seem to work with my code. When tried they produced this error: `PandaSQLException: (sqlite3.ProgrammingError) Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 0 supplied`.  I can put them in quotes without an error but then the variable is treated as a string. I have seen `.execute()` [(1)](https://techoverflow.net/2019/10/14/how-to-fix-sqlite3-python-incorrect-number-of-bindings-supplied-the-current-statement-uses-1-supplied/)[(2)](https://libraries.io/pypi/pysqldf)as a way to pass the query variables, however when I change the last line to `sqldf.execute(q, [varMonth])` I received the error `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'execute'`.

Any advice on how to use variables in an SQL query on JupyterNotebooks using *pandasql*?

Comment: if there is no special method to use variables then use normal string formatig - `"... {} ....".format(varMonth)` or f-string - `f"... {varMonth} ...."`

Comment: How did you get `sqldf` ? maybe you created function `sqldf()` but you should create instance of some class - `sqldf = SomeClass()` - and then you would have `sqldf.execute()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that [pandasql](https://github.com/yhat/pandasql/) and [pysqldf](https://github.com/airtoxin/pysqldf) don't have method to use variables in query like for normal database - so you have to use string formatting

```
q = """
    SELECT
        *,
        strftime('%m', "DATE DUE") as "months"
    FROM 
        year2020
    WHERE 
        "months" = "{}"    
""".format(varMonth)
```

or f-string

```
q = f"""
    SELECT
        *,
        strftime('%m', "DATE DUE") as "months"
    FROM 
        year2020
    WHERE 
        "months" = "{varMonth}"    
"""
```

---

**EDIT:**

I checked source code for both modules and both use [pandas.read_sql()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html) which can get `params=(...)` like for normal database but modules don't use it.

If you use `?`, `%s`, etc. then you get only error because `params` is `None`